# Assigning value to location.href in Chrome by keydown event only works the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, spotify

Assigning value to window.location.href by keydown event only works the first time in Chrome (i.e. multiple RIGHT ARROW keydown events). The exception is ENTER key. Seems to be working fine in Firefox and IE.

Is this some sort of security measurement?

http://jsfiddle.net/k9pwB/

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    switch (key) {
        case 39:
        case 13:
            console.log('play');
            window.location.href = 'spotify:track:6JEK0CvvjDjjMUBFoXShNZ';
    }
});
```

Comment: other than handling invalid urls slightly different, it works for me in chrome...are you sure you have focus on the result window in the jsfiddle page when you press the right arrow key?

Comment: Yes. Did you press the right arrow key multiple times and the track restarted each time?

Comment: well no..nothing "played" if that's what you're asking..on jsfiddle.net that url means nothing, you are trying to change the url to url that is invalid.  But i did see that action and the `console.log('play')` message happening multiple times

Comment: The event is triggered every time and "play" is always displayed. Spotify however will only start playing the song on the first event. By using enter key or Firefox/IE (with any key), it works on every event.

I see now that it loses focus on the window and will work if I mouse  click back into it first.